# Send a base64 gif with ajax, very long

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

So, i have a script for capture a video from a webcam. After the record, i convert, with javascript, this video (a blob) into a base64 encode, and i put this base64 data into an `image.src` for have a preview :

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function() {
  base64data = reader.result;
  img.src = base64data;
}
```

After that, I can see my GIF in base64 on my page.

I have a script for crop and resize the GIF, and after that, i send this base64data to a PHP script with AJAX :

```
var gif = $('.generated-img').attr('src').replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '');
gif = gif.match(/.{1,500000}/g);
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "/webcam/",
  data: {image_gif:gif, crop_x:x, crop_y:y, crop_w:w, crop_h:h, gif:true},
  success: function () {
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
  }
});
```

`var gif` (my base64data) is a very long string, approximatly 2 000 000 of characters. So, I have to cut it into several pieces (500 000 characters each) otherwise ajax does not send.

**My problem :** This ajax request is very long to execute (between 30s and 2minutes), i'm on a good server with a good connection. The problem is the size of my base64data.. 2M of characters is too much for ajax.

Do you have any solutions for me ? I need to send this data to php, but without this long execution time.. Thanks !

Comment: 2M characters is apprx. 7.5 mb, this would be like a standard file upload, you cannot rush it. So show a process bar to the user and keep sending the data

Comment: no, when i right click and save my gif, the size is 1,30mo

Comment: well my bad, it was 7.5 megabits not bytes :D